# jQuery addClass removeClass

Tags: jquery

Can someone please tell me why the class 'selected' is only being added and not removed here?

```
jQuery("area").on('click', function(){

    jQuery('selected', this).removeClass('selected');

    jQuery(this).addClass('selected');

 });
```

Comment: You should tell us if any of these worked and choose answer as correct if any of these answers worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are getting it wrong. Use this

```
jQuery('.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "selected" is a class. So to fix change your code to this:

```
jQuery('.selected', this).removeClass('selected');
```

See the added dot(.) on the selector.